# @JsonIgnore ignored for public getter

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Hello I have read all the posts on this, but nothing seems to help

I have a public getter that points to a circular structure that I do not want serialized into Json.  I have looked through the other posts and tried the suggestions but nothing works.

Currently, I am using ObjectMapper @JsonIgnore and @JsonAutoDetect like this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
public class Bah {

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }
```

However, the getter is still being serialized into my Json structure.  But when I rename getFoo to something without get (e.g. foo()) it works, but "public getX()" seems to override the @JsonIgnore

What am I missing?  I'm sure its something dumb

Thanks
Peter

Comment: What happens if you remove `@JsonAutoDetect`?

Comment: Removing the JsonAutoDetect has no effect.  Jackson still tries the serialize the public getter.

Comment: Interestingly, when I try to make a standalone test case, it works as expected.  So the example I posted probably works.  There is something special/different about my actual class.  My class also has XML annotations like this: @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD), 
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo"), @XmlType(propOrder = {... Could Jackson be fighting with javax.xml?

Comment: Ah, so you are mixing both XML and JSON annotations... Sorry, can't help on that one, I do JSON and JSON only...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I got it, and as predicted it was really dumb!

Turns out I had both com.codehaus.jackson and com.fasterxml.jackson in my project.  The ObjectMapper came from fasterxml and the annotations came from codehaus >:-P

Now everything is working as expected as expected.  Thank you all for the help.
P

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling `AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS` in your `ObjectMapper`.  You can do this wherever you are instantiating `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS);
```

Or, extend `ObjectMapper` and use the custom one throughout your project:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        disable(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS);
        // more project-wide config
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Will it still be able to use @JsonProperty to serialize desired getters?

Comment: Yes.  By default Jackson follows Bean naming conventions to determine which properties to serialize; disabling `AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS` will prevent Jackson from doing this.  With that feature disabled, you _must_ annotate getters for all fields you want to be serialized.

Comment: Gah!  After disabling getters, now I can not turn on serialization :-( JsonValue and JsonProperty seem to have no effect.  I guess this is consistent with their behavior before...

Comment: Hm, that is strange. You don't need the `@JsonAutoDetect` annotation anymore if you disable `AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS` on your object mapper, are you annotating your getters with `@JsonProperty("fieldName")` and still getting the error?